# Jsonp not working with getJSON jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jsonp

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://quanta.net16.net/wordpressnew/test.php?jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
    alert('swag');
  });
});
```

this is my json call and my json is wrapped properly in ?({object})
but the alert is not popping it doesn't show any javascript errors
please help with any possible fixes
[link to json creating php](http://quanta.net16.net/wordpressnew/test.php)
the url is open for access if required

Comment: You haven't given much information for people to work with here. Can you include an example of the JSON returned? Perhaps by just performing a curl request to the same URL?

Comment: do you get any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` errors in your console?

Comment: When the contents in `http://quanta.net16.net/wordpressnew/test.php?jsoncallback=?` is executed, it will not be a perfect JavaScript.

Comment: add header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); on your php file at the top

Comment: I get this error console chrome
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://quanta.net16.net/wordpressnew/test.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://api.jquery.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: Shubham, check the console while running my snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not set the Cross Origin Resorce Sharing header properly

Answer (score 0):

The output of the [request](http://quanta.net16.net/wordpressnew/test.php?jsoncallback=?) is:

```
?([{"id":84,"title":"Solar Decathlon","url":"http:\/\/quanta.net16.net\/wordpressnew\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/12\/grp4_s2.jpg","isFeatured":false,"isNews":false,"college":false,"time":1450076653,"summary":""},{"id":80,"title":"HUDCO UNIT 2012-13","url":false,"isFeatured":false,"isNews":false,"college":false,"time":1450076349,"summary":"HUDCO UNIT 2012-13 got the first citation in 55th annual NASA convention 2012-13 for their design of 24*7 day and night permanent shelter for urban homeless.The entire work is taken by HUDCO,New delhi to work more on it.Also the entire work has been asked to sent by Dr.amod kumar from st.stefens hospital,tiss hazati, Delhi. and […]"},{"id":77,"title":"Egyptian Artwork","url":"http:\/\/quanta.net16.net\/wordpressnew\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/12\/XU0zTIXjslCgCGAULTlAVz3AEbLzNFdsB1OVFJH7zWYw222-h220.jpg","isFeatured":false,"isNews":false,"college":false,"time":1450075669,"summary":"Made By the students of all the batch 3102 etc,this is some artwork info.Made By the students of all the batch 3102 etc,this is some artwork infoMade By the students of all the batch 3102 etc,this is some artwork infoMade By the students of all the batch 3102 etc,this is some artwork infoMade By the […]"},{"id":67,"title":"Collezione – 2015","url":"http:\/\/quanta.net16.net\/wordpressnew\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/12\/event2015.jpg","isFeatured":false,"isNews":false,"college":false,"time":1450074883,"summary":"Collezione – 2015 the Annual Fashion Show of the School Of Fashion & Textile Design, The new age designers put a jaw dropping collections, for various category of Indian Ethnic, Resort, Cruize, Swimwear, Westernwear formal & men\u2019s wear."},{"id":63,"title":"International Tour: \u201cWorld is a book, those who do no travel read only one page\u201d \u2013 St. Agustine","url":"http:\/\/quanta.net16.net\/wordpressnew\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/12\/irfw_23.jpg","isFeatured":false,"isNews":false,"college":false,"time":1450071633,"summary":"True to ever word, students along with our experienced faculty get to have a great exposure to world of Fashion Art & Design. We host premium events with visits to Premier Vision, Art galleries, Meeting Designers and much more for an unmatched international exposure and witness latest in fashion, upcoming trend & So forth. Come […]"},{"id":53,"title":"yoloswag asdfasdfa","url":false,"isFeatured":false,"isNews":false,"college":false,"time":1449835439,"summary":"asdfasdf"},{"id":50,"title":"asdf","url":false,"isFeatured":false,"isNews":false,"college":false,"time":1449834299,"summary":"asdfasdfasdasdfasdfasdfsdfasd"},{"id":48,"title":"asdfasdf","url":false,"isFeatured":false,"isNews":false,"college":false,"time":1449834004,"summary":"asdfasdfasdfasdf"},{"id":45,"title":"asdfasdfasdfasdfad","url":false,"isFeatured":false,"isNews":false,"college":false,"time":1449833570,"summary":"adsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf"},{"id":43,"title":"Story of my life","url":false,"isFeatured":false,"isNews":false,"college":false,"time":1449830857,"summary":""}]);
```

Which is not a valid JavaScript. A function call cannot start with: `?()`. Instead, I would ask you to create a function that uses it, say:

```
function callJson (data) {
  alert(data.length);
  console.log(data.length);
}
```

Now, just give a request to:

```
http://quanta.net16.net/wordpressnew/test.php?jsoncallback=callJson
```

And that gives the output, `callJson({json-data})`.

**Working Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  function callJson (data) {
    alert(data.length);
    console.log(data.length);
  }
  $.getJSON("https://jsonp.afeld.me/?url=http://quanta.net16.net/wordpressnew/test.php?jsoncallback=callJson", function (data) {
    debugger;
  }).fail(function(data) {
    // console.log( data );
    res = data.responseText.trim().replace("callJson(", "");
    res = res.substr(0, res.length-2);
    res = JSON.parse(res);
    console.log(res);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Corrected the snippet. Check the console.